# Android Debugger becomes detached

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am perplexed by the behavior of Android debugger using Android Studio. It just cuts out during my debug session, then device not available.  I seem to also lose all logcat files when this happens so don't detect a crash. App does not crash either so ... I am trying to debug a WebView and its corresponding WebViewClient but in the middle of my debug session the debugger just dies. Then it says that no device found when I try to rebuild and run as debug session. I have to unplug and plug back in the USB cord. Only then if I am lucky does the device reappear. But usually debug session lasts just a little while and then cuts off.

```
 adb kill-server 
 adb start-server
```

Does not help. Device is no longer available. What could be going on here? Debugging debugger is really tough

Here is what console says:

```
 Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/com.myapp.debug
 java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

If I then try to debug again I get:

```
  Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/com.myapp.debug
  com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device 'b3941da' not found
```

I have had this happen on two Android devices a Galaxy III, and Note Android 4.03. Not sure whats going on here.  I do see power saving mode some times kicks in on one of the devices ... Turned off power mode, but still see this happening quickly right after trying to load app.

When Debugger gets cut off why is my logcat also destroyed? I mean what's the thinking in doing that? I get one entry left everything else whipped out:

```
    01-01 00:00:00.000 0-0/? E/Internal: device offline
```

To be frank that's kind of frustrating .....

Now I also see:

```
 Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
 Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers guys!

Comment: Looks like only the debugger leaves me hanging also you guys! nice! very nice!

Comment: Check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/viewing-modes.html?origin=old_help